dpkg: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.38' not found (required by dpkg)
I get this error when I try to make an installation command in the terminal and I can't resolve it...
/usr/bin/dpkg: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.38' not found (
required by /usr/bin/dpkg)
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
The problem is with dpkg
for example when I try this
sudo dpkg --configure -a
I get this
dpkg: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.38' not found (required by dpkg)
Globally, every command related to dpkg creates this error.


/usr/bin/dpkg: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version 'GLIBC_2.38' not found

This error means: you are using dpkg that was linked on a system with GLIBC_2.38 (or newer) on a system with system GLIBC that is older.
This could happen if you copied the dpkg binary from another (newer) system. (Don't do that -- your system should have had its own working dpkg binary).
You should restore your dpkg from a recovery disk, or re-install your system if you don't know how to use the recovery disk.
This question is also off-topic on stackoverflow.
